# Trying to set/reset the badge count to 0

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am fairly new to Swift Development and trying out new things and one of them is Local Notifications.

What I am trying is to reset/set the badge count when the app reopens.

The code/answers I have seen on stack overflow are for versions prior to iOS 16 which is this.
`UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0`

I tried following the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/4031317-setbadgecount) but cannot get it to work. Below is the code.

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

class NotificationManager{
    static let instance  = NotificationManager()
    
    func requestAuth(){
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge, .provisional]) { granted, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                // Handle the error here.
                print("Error\(error)")
            }else{
                print("Success")
            }
            
            // Provisional authorization granted.
        }
    }
    
    func scheduleNoti(){
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title="This is my first Notification"
        content.subtitle = "This is a sample body"
        content.sound = .default
        content.badge = 1
        
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5.0, repeats: false)
        
        // three types of notification trigger // time, calendar, location
        let req = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(req)
    }

    func resetBadgeCount(){
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount(0) { error in
            print("Error \(error.debugDescription)") // returns nil
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 40){
            Button("Request"){
                NotificationManager.instance.requestAuth()
            }
            Button("Schedule NOTI"){
                NotificationManager.instance.scheduleNoti()
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            NotificationManager.instance.resetBadgeCount()
            //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount(0) 
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

The App create a new badge count but it does not set it back to zero when I reopen it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot get it to work"? Please describe how it does not work. What did the code do? What dd you expect it to do instead?

Comment: @Sweeper As mentioned in the question, It should set the badge count to 0 when it is back on the view. It creates a badge count when I Schedule the notification, but once I reopen the app it does not set the badge count back to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onAppear` doesn't get called when you momentarily close the app and reopen it again.

You can detect a `scenePhase` change instead. If it changes to `.active`, that means your app has been "opened".

Read it from the environment...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
```

Then replace `onAppear` with:

```
.onChange(of: scenePhase) { oldValue, newValue in
    if newValue == .active {
        NotificationManager.instance.resetBadgeCount()
    }
}
```

Comment: does this mean that onAppear only runs when the views are changed(going to another view and coming back to it ) / initialized?

Comment: @malfoy Yes that's basically how it works. Note that `onAppear` is also called when the view's `id` changes. You can think of it as the view with the old id disappears, and the view with the new id appears.