# UIApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber is deprecated

Tags: swift, swiftui, notifications

```
.onAppear {
  UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

It says that applicationIconBadgeNumber was depreciated and I have to use `setBadge()`, how can I use that in this code? Because it says that

> applicationIconBadgeNumber was deprecated in iOS 17.0: Use -[UNUserNotificationCenter setBadgeCount:withCompletionHandler:] instead.

And now I ask me how to solve that problem

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77428967/5133585

Comment: Isn't it clearly stated on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622918-applicationiconbadgenumber ? “Use setBadgeCount(_:withCompletionHandler:) instead.”

Comment: I didn't understand that you need .current(), I always tried UNUserNotificationCenter.setBadgeCount(0), I also consulted this website, but I didn't understand it there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```swift
.onAppear {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount(0, withCompletionHandler: nil))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when I write the code like this, it works without any problems.

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount(0)
completionHandler()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As the deprecation not clearly states, you need to call `UNUserNotificationCenter.setBadgeCount(_:withCompletionHandler:)` instead - [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/4031317-setbadgecount).

```
.onAppear {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount(0)
}
```

If you want to handle possible errors, pass a completion handler as well:

```
.onAppear {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount(0) { error in
    guard let error else {
      // Badge count was successfully updated
      return
    }
    // Replace this with proper error handling
    print(error)
  }
}
```